# Motherboard won’t turn on with front switch, but works when I short it manually with a screwdriver

Tags: motherboard, power, front-panel

I have a [Asus TUF X570 (WiFi)](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/TUF-Gaming/TUF-GAMING-X570-PLUS-WI-FI/) board that I've been using for over a year without issue. I was adding a second m.2 SSD and suddenly could no longer power on using the front panel power switch. Removing the connector and shorting the switch pins with a screwdriver boots the computer properly.

A continuity test of the switch shows it to be working correctly (beeps when front switch is pressed).

Is there any reason that a working switch would not cause the switch terminals to switch on the motherboard?

Comment: Could the connector have come loose--looked like it was still connected when it wasn't?  After your tests did you try putting it back together and see if it works?

Comment: Yes Putting the switch connector back it still does not work.